# Plausible reason for a VPN to point to a country different to the one you are connected to?

Tags: vpn

I am using NordVPN, but I believe this applies to VPNs in general.

For some time now, I have been worried about the reliability of my VPN provider, especially because information that shows up when accessing pages do not seem to reflect the country I am supposedly connected to via their server (more times than not).

What bothers me is that I connect to a server in a country (say Japan) via a P2P connection and then my YouTube ads and Google Maps location point to other places (like Hong Kong, Taiwan and sometimes even Ireland).

Is this common with VPN servers, even in P2P connections? What does it mean to encounter situations like this and should I take any measures regarding my VPN provider?

Comment: Major VPNs are known to be VPNs. It's very likely your Browser **Language** and **Time Zone** reflect your actual location.

Comment: Yes because google use a lot more than just ip to keep track of you.Simple masking your ip doesn't hide you from the big brother

Comment: To get a better idea of "where you are", grab the public IP address as seen by websites and run a whois search on it.

Comment: Unless you need to look like you are coming from a certain country, what are you worried about?

Comment: @multithr3at3d in my case, usually because google thinks my VPS is in Saudi and shows me results in Arabic :-)  Just sayin'